# When I use networkx.draw to draw the network, python2 and python3 use the same program, but python2 cannot draw correctly

Tags: python, networkx

When I use `networkx.draw` to draw the network,using the same program with python2 and python3 , but python2 cannot draw correctly. Left is py3, right is py2.

```sh
 import scipy
 import numpy as np
 import networkx as nx
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
 N = [("n{}".format(i), 0) for i in range(1,7)] + \ 
     [("n{}".format(i), 1) for i in range(7,13)] + \ 
     [("n{}".format(i), 2) for i in range(13,19)]
 E = [("n1","n2"), ("n1","n3"), ("n1","n5"),
      ("n2","n4"),
      ("n3","n6"), ("n3","n9"),
      ("n4","n5"), ("n4","n6"), ("n4","n8"),
      ("n5","n14"),
      ("n7","n8"), ("n7","n9"), ("n7","n11"),
      ("n8","n10"), ("n8","n11"), ("n8", "n12"),
      ("n9","n10"), ("n9","n14"),
      ("n10","n12"),
      ("n11","n18"),
      ("n13","n15"), ("n13","n16"), ("n13","n18"),
      ("n14","n16"), ("n14","n18"),
      ("n15","n16"), ("n15","n18"),
      ("n17","n18")]

 G = nx.Graph()
 print(list(map(lambda x: x[0], N)))
 G.add_nodes_from(list(map(lambda x: x[0], N)))
 G.add_edges_from(E)
 ncolor = ['r']*6+['g']*6+['b']*6
 nsize = [700] * 6 + [700] * 6 + [700] * 6
 nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold',
         node_color=list(ncolor), node_size=nsize)
 plt.savefig("graph.png")
 plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: the graphs seem isomorphic...?

Comment: i try to mark node by different color,like n1 is red。but in python2 ,the color is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pythons older than 3.6 dictionaries does not maintain insertion order. Hence you might end up with those colors being assigned to different nodes. Try enforcing a nodelist when drawing using `nodelist`:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(list(map(lambda x: x[0], N)))
G.add_edges_from(E)
ncolor = ['r']*6+['g']*6+['b']*6
nsize = [700] * 6 + [700] * 6 + [700] * 6
nodelist = [n[0] for n in N] 
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold',
     node_color=list(ncolor), node_size=nsize,
     nodelist=nodelist)
plt.savefig("graph.png")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the differences between the figures is only the color (and for sure the positioning), then you can try to replace

```
ncolor = ['r']*6+['g']*6+['b']*6
```

with the following:

```
color_dict = {"n{}".format(i): "r" for i in range(1, 7)}
color_dict.update({"n{}".format(i): "g" for i in range(7, 13)})
color_dict.update({"n{}".format(i): "b" for i in range(13, 19)})
ncolor = [color_dict[node] for node in G]
```

### Background

If I remember correctly, `dict` in python 2 do not necessarily preserve the order of added elements. Hence, "n0" does not need to be the first element in `G`. In python 3, they started to preserve the ordering and consequently you color the desired nodes.